# How to print out the elements of a 2D array in erlang

Tags: arrays, recursion, printing, count, erlang

I have been trying to print out the elements of a 2D array in erlang, however, as there are no loops and therefor no simple way to increment a variable, let alone two.  I have seen one or two recursive functions for making a single loop, however, I have not been able to turn this code into a nested loop.  This is the code I have been using.

```
-module(test2). 
-export([do_loop/0,loop/1]).

do_loop() ->
    loop(0).

loop(10) ->
    ok;
loop(Count) ->
    io:format("~w~n", [Count]),
    loop(Count+1).
```

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:
Here is the code for the array

```
create( X, Y ) -> array:new( [{size, X}, {default, array:new( [{size, Y}] )}] ).

get( X, Y, Array ) -> array:get( Y, array:get(X, Array) ).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array module provides `foldl` and `foldr` to fold over the array from low to high and high to low, respectively.

Using `foldl` and recursing into second level arrays (and beyond):

```
-module(test).
-export([dump/1]).

dump(Array) ->
    array:foldl(fun inner_dump/3, [], Array).
```

The dump function accepts the array and starts the fold.  `array:foldl` takes a fold function, an intial accumulator, and the array to fold.  It takes each element of the array in turn and calls `FoldFun(Index, Element, Accumulator)`, the return value of that call becomes the new accumulator.  For this function I have defined the accumulator to be the list of indexes from parent arrays.

```
inner_dump( Index, ArrayOrElement, Previous) ->
    case array:is_array(ArrayOrElement) of
        false ->
            io:format("~p ~p~n", [lists:reverse([Index|Previous]), ArrayOrElement]),
            Previous;
        true ->
            array:foldl(fun inner_dump/3, [Index|Previous], ArrayOrElement),
            Previous
    end.
```

This is the fold function.  If the passed element is not an array, prepend its index to the list of parent indexes, then reverse that list and print it with the element. (This gives the index of each array starting from the outermost one as expected)

If the passed element is a sub array, prepend its index to the list of parent indexes and fold over it in the same manner.

This will allow you print out arrays of arbitrary depth, and will still function even if each sub array is not the same size.

Here is an example using the array `[[a,b,c],[1,2,3],["yes","no","maybe"]]`:

```
2> Array.
{array,3,0,undefined,
       {{array,3,10,undefined,
               {a,b,c,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
                  undefined,undefined}},
        {array,3,10,undefined,
               {1,2,3,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
                undefined,undefined}},
        {array,3,10,undefined,
               {"yes","no","maybe",undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
                undefined,undefined,undefined}},
        undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
        undefined}}
3> test:dump(Array).
[0,0] a
[0,1] b
[0,2] c
[1,0] 1
[1,1] 2
[1,2] 3
[2,0] "yes"
[2,1] "no"
[2,2] "maybe"
[]
```